# What's the eclipse c++ search regex dialect?

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to learn more about the regex syntax of the search and replace function in eclipse c++.

Does it use it's own regex syntax(in this case anyone knows a good tutorial) or does it use the syntax of another language(like java regex, grep, perl regex)?

Comment: I think it understands Perl regex.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse search and replace feature [uses Java regex](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-findreplace.htm):

> The regular expression must respect Java Regex.

However, one of the peculiarities is that you cannot match zero-legnth strings (i.e. `(?=,)` won't match the empty string before `,`). In such cases, use capturing groups in the regex and use backreferences to those groups in the replacement patterns (e.g. to add newlines after a comma use `,` in the search and `$0\n` in the replacement).